# Could you provide a theroy to calculate the possibility?

Tags: probability

Qusetion: Imagine that we have a total of $n$ coins, which have been serialised from $1$ to $n$. We know that the probability that the $i$- th coin will be heads up after being tossed is $$P(i) = \frac{2i}{2i+1}$$. What is the probability that the number of coins that are heads up after we have tossed n coins will be an odd number?

So far I still don't know how to approach this question. The largest problem I enhance is how to determine the distribution of the coins since each coin has a different possibility for itself to be heads up. There is no need to provide the full solution, could you please offer me a possible method to approach it?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the following polynomial
$$Q(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n{\left(1-P_i+P_i x\right)} = \sum_{k=0}^n {c_k x^k}$$
Where $c_k$ is the kth order coefficient of $Q(x)$ in it's expanded form. Notice that $c_k$  is equal to the probability of "k coins are heads up". Then the question boils down to finding the sum of odd order coefficients of Q(x)

That sum is equal to $\frac{Q(1) - Q(-1)}{2}$

I'll let you figure out why :)